# Layout and Capacitance of 24/12 Inverter

Tags: layout, vlsi

Consider below layout:
[image]

It is from CMOS VLSI Design Book by West-Harris.

1. Why it is called 24/12 lambda inverter? I could not estimate its width/length so it match 24 and 12.
2. Why its capacitance is 9 times of a unit (4 lambda) transistor ?

Comment: OK question. Apposite answer by Joe. BUT a lot more people would benefit from a bit more detail in the question which somewhat de-jargionified the matter being discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 24/12 means that the PMOS has a width of 24 lambda and the NMOS has a width of 12 lambda. That's a total of 36 lambda of gate width, which is 9 times as much as a 4 lambda transistor. Therefore, the capacitance of the output node of the inverter is also about 9 times bigger than that of the 4-lambda transistor.

Comment: So how 12-lambda width and 24-lambda width can be extracted from layout? Which are the spacing rules lead to 12 and 24?

Comment: The actual dimensions of lambda are process-dependent, so you have find out exactly what manufacturing process will be used (TSMC 250nm, IBM 130nm, etc.) The standard gate length for a transistor is 2 lambda so you have to look at the ratio of width:length to figure out the transistor width in lambda.

Comment: As long as i know, this book does not use lambda rules of deep sub-micron. However i'm not sure if this layout is based on basic lambda-rules or not..

Comment: There's no way to tell visually whether a layout was done using scalable lambda rules or actual process rules.

Comment: I should note that min size NMOS got 4/2 ratios. So PMOS with 24/2 got 6C capacitance of min-size NMOS, NMOS with 12/2 ratios got 3C of min-size nmos, totaly: 6C+3C = 9C. As Joe Hass Mentioned: (24+12)/4 = 9 :)